# How to create different object types using spring boot and query annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I need to create an object that has all the fields of a table and that some information from another table is together (not all).

> @Query( "SELECT new com.nowigo.systemsheet.User.User (U.id, U.name)
>   FROM user U INNER JOIN U.promoter P where P.id = ?1") public
>   List findAllById(Long promoterId);
>
> @Query( "SELECT U.id,U.name,P.name FROM user U INNER JOIN U.promoter P
>   where P.id = ?1")

Entity User

```java
package com.nowigo.systemsheet.User;

import com.nowigo.systemsheet.base.BaseEntity;
import com.nowigo.systemsheet.Promoter.Promoter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
//@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "promoter_id" )
    private Promoter promoter;

    private String name;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String description;

    @Column(name = "enabled", columnDefinition = "tinyint")
    private Boolean enabled;

    private Integer types;

    private String permissions;

    private Long restricted_event_id;

    private Long restricted_cashlesscash_id;

    private Long restricted_reseller_id;


    @Column(name = "time_begin_reseller_bat", columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date time_begin_reseller_bat;

    @Column(name = "time_end_reseller_bat", columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date time_end_reseller_bat;

    @Column(name = "time_begin_reseller_individual", columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date time_begin_reseller_individual;

    @Column(name = "time_end_reseller_individual", columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    private Date time_end_reseller_individual;

    private Long img_id;

    @Column(name = "can_make_return_operation", columnDefinition = "tinyint")
    private Boolean can_make_return_operation;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getRestricted_reseller_id() {
        return restricted_reseller_id;
    }

    public void setRestricted_reseller_id(Long restricted_reseller_id) {
        this.restricted_reseller_id = restricted_reseller_id;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Integer getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(Integer types) {
        this.types = types;
    }

    public String getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(String premissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public Long getRestricted_event_id() {
        return restricted_event_id;
    }

    public void setRestricted_event_id(Long restricted_event_id) {
        this.restricted_event_id = restricted_event_id;
    }

    public Long getRestricted_cashlesscash_id() {
        return restricted_cashlesscash_id;
    }

    public void setRestricted_cashlesscash_id(Long restricted_cashlesscash_id) {
        this.restricted_cashlesscash_id = restricted_cashlesscash_id;
    }

    public Long getRestricted_resellet_id() {
        return restricted_reseller_id;
    }

    public void setRestricted_resellet_id(Long restricted_resellet_id) {
        this.restricted_reseller_id = restricted_resellet_id;
    }

    public Date getTime_begin_reseller_bat() {
        return time_begin_reseller_bat;
    }

    public void setTime_begin_reseller_bat(Date time_begin_reseller_bat) {
        this.time_begin_reseller_bat = time_begin_reseller_bat;
    }

    public Date getTime_end_reseller_bat() {
        return time_end_reseller_bat;
    }

    public void setTime_end_reseller_bat(Date time_end_reseller_bat) {
        this.time_end_reseller_bat = time_end_reseller_bat;
    }

    public Date getTime_begin_reseller_individual() {
        return time_begin_reseller_individual;
    }

    public void setTime_begin_reseller_individual(Date time_begin_reseller_individual) {
        this.time_begin_reseller_individual = time_begin_reseller_individual;
    }

    public Date getTime_end_reseller_individual() {
        return time_end_reseller_individual;
    }

    public void setTime_end_reseller_individual(Date time_end_reseller_individual) {
        this.time_end_reseller_individual = time_end_reseller_individual;
    }

    public Long getImg_id() {
        return img_id;
    }

    public void setImg_id(Long img_id) {
        this.img_id = img_id;
    }

    public Boolean getCan_make_return_operation() {
        return can_make_return_operation;
    }

    public void setCan_make_return_operation(Boolean can_make_return_operation) {
        this.can_make_return_operation = can_make_return_operation;
    }

    public Boolean getCan_make_register_operation() {
        return can_make_register_operation;
    }

    public void setCan_make_register_operation(Boolean can_make_register_operation) {
        this.can_make_register_operation = can_make_register_operation;
    }

    @Column(name = "can_make_register_operation", columnDefinition = "tinyint")
    private Boolean can_make_register_operation;

    public Promoter getPromoter() {
        return promoter;
    }

    public void setPromoter(Promoter promoter) {
        this.promoter = promoter;
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.getId();
    }



    public User() {
    }

    public User(Promoter promoter, String name, String username, String password, String description, Boolean enabled, Integer types, String permissions, Long restricted_event_id, Long restricted_cashlesscash_id, Long restricted_reseller_id, Date time_begin_reseller_bat, Date time_end_reseller_bat, Date time_begin_reseller_individual, Date time_end_reseller_individual, Long img_id, Boolean can_make_return_operation, Boolean can_make_register_operation) {
        this.promoter = promoter;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.description = description;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.types = types;
        this.permissions = permissions;
        this.restricted_event_id = restricted_event_id;
        this.restricted_cashlesscash_id = restricted_cashlesscash_id;
        this.restricted_reseller_id = restricted_reseller_id;
        this.time_begin_reseller_bat = time_begin_reseller_bat;
        this.time_end_reseller_bat = time_end_reseller_bat;
        this.time_begin_reseller_individual = time_begin_reseller_individual;
        this.time_end_reseller_individual = time_end_reseller_individual;
        this.img_id = img_id;
        this.can_make_return_operation = can_make_return_operation;
        this.can_make_register_operation = can_make_register_operation;
    }

}
```

Entity Promoter

```
package com.nowigo.systemsheet.Promoter;

import com.nowigo.systemsheet.User.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.nowigo.systemsheet.base.BaseEntity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
//@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id")
public class Promoter extends BaseEntity implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "promoter", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<User> user;

    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    private String address;

    private String address_number;

    private String address_extra;

    private String address_area;

    private String city;

    private String cnpx;

    private String ierg;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress_number() {
        return address_number;
    }

    public void setAddress_number(String address_number) {
        this.address_number = address_number;
    }

    public String getAddress_extra() {
        return address_extra;
    }

    public void setAddress_extra(String address_extra) {
        this.address_extra = address_extra;
    }

    public String getAddress_area() {
        return address_area;
    }

    public void setAddress_area(String address_area) {
        this.address_area = address_area;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCnpx() {
        return cnpx;
    }

    public void setCnpx(String cnpx) {
        this.cnpx = cnpx;
    }

    public String getIerg() {
        return ierg;
    }

    public void setIerg(String ierg) {
        this.ierg = ierg;
    }

    public List<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(List<User> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Promoter(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



    public Promoter() {
    }

    public Promoter(List<User> user, String password, String address, String address_number, String address_extra, String address_area, String city, String cnpx, String ierg) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.address = address;
        this.address_number = address_number;
        this.address_extra = address_extra;
        this.address_area = address_area;
        this.city = city;
        this.cnpx = cnpx;
        this.ierg = ierg;
    }
}
```

User repository

```java
package com.nowigo.systemsheet.User;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;


public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public List<User> findByPromoterId(Long promoterId);

        @Query(value = "SELECT U.id,U.name, P.address FROM sheetsystem.user U JOIN sheetsystem.promoter P ON U.promoter_id = P.id where P.id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<User> findAllById(Long promoterId);

}
```

Expected:

```
    {
            "id": 17,
            "promoter": {
                "id": 4,
                "address": "Av. John Wick"
            },
            "name": "usuario",
            "username": null,
            "description": null,
            "enabled": null,
            "types": null,
            "permissions": null,
            "restricted_event_id": null,
            "restricted_cashlesscash_id": null,
            "restricted_reseller_id": null,
            "time_begin_reseller_bat": null,
            "time_end_reseller_bat": null,
            "time_begin_reseller_individual": null,
            "time_end_reseller_individual": null,
            "img_id": null,
            "can_make_return_operation": null,
            "can_make_register_operation": null,
            "restricted_resellet_id": null
      }
```

I get this:

> The field can_make_register_operation is not found

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe using an entity class to return a partially hydrated object from a native query is good practice.  Once you get that instance into the businses layer, you may loose some context in knowing whether it can be persisted later or whether its immutable all because its technically an instance of an annotated entity. You run the risk that someone might accidentally merge the changes to the data store and loose data.

Personally I think its much better practice as well as separation of concerns to design an intermediate object that the persistence layer returns that uniquely fits the data you're after, one which clearly identifies that the returned object is immutable, cannot be changed, nor can be persisted, like this:

```
public class UserProfileAddress {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Promoter promoter;

  UserProfileAddress(Integer id, String name, Promoter promoter) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.promoter = promoter;
  }

  // .. getter/setters
}
```

You should then be able to write the query as

```
SELECT new com.package.UserProfileAddress( u.id, u.name, u.promoter )
  FROM User u
  JOIN FETCH u.promoter
 WHERE u.promoter.id = :promoterId
```

Now you're using a portable JPA query and not a native query, which makes your code than more resilient to potential future changes should you decide to change from one data store to another.

As to your error about what was expected; you'll need to provide more context.

Comment: What if I need to get a Promoter with limited information, just like User, what would the query look like?

Comment: You would simply add additional predicates to the WHERE clause.